# Downloadable Font failed, IIS

Tags: iis, fonts, http-status-code-404, mime-types, iis-8.5

The custom fonts I am using on my website aren't provided by IIS 8.5.
I have set the MIME-Types as followed:

```
<remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
<remove fileExtension=".woff" />
<remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
<remove fileExtension=".eot" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
```

.eot works fine (or at least doesn't give me errors in the web debugging windows).
The other formats (woff, woff2, tff) won't work and give me a 404 Not found error.

I think IIS has access to the fonts folder as the eot files work just fine.
Firefox throws this error:

*GET 
https://prefix.someurl.iis/Resources/Fonts/GlyphaLTStd.woff [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 53ms]*

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think these MIME type has been built-in the IIS 8.5.  You don't have to do anything to download these files.  It must be something else blocked your font download.

Comment: @WillHuang Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I was able to fix it.
Turns out my lazyness got in the way again (why does this keep happening..?).

Lazy me copied the reference source paths in the font-face declarations so the CSS file didn't get the source-url properly somehow.

Hope this helps other people.